# Writing an array (or pandas dataframe) to mysql/sqlite database using django orm

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, pandas

I'm wondering what the best way to store an array and/or pandas dataframe into an sqlite or mysql database using the django orm. I have some data in a pandas dataframe, something like this:

```
data = {'a': [[0,0.1,0.2,0.3],[5,10,15,20]], 'b': [[0,10,20,30],[20,30,40,50]]}
```

I'm considering storing it in a database like this:

```
data_name    index    data
---------    -----    ----
   a           0        5
   a          0.1       10
   .           .        .
   .           .        .
   .           .        .
   b           0        20
   b           10       30
   .           .        .
   .           .        .
   .           .        .
```

Is this a logical structure? And if so, how might I build a custom django db class/field in order to input it into the database?

I have an object like this

```
def MyClass(models.Model):
    my_df = SomeCustomField() # how would you implement this part?

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Does it make more sense to serialize it and store it in a serialized format in a single db entry?

Each of these arrays could be 100 elements, will querying so many related rows have a negative impact on performance?